# Adding punctuations and other characters to stopwords?

Tags: python, list, performance, python-3.8, stop-words

For the assignment, we manually use stopwords in order to return sentences without them. However we also have to remove periods, commas, question marks, punctuations and I cant figure out how to do that because if it's attached to the word, it won't remove. here is my code. For example, if I put prep_text('how was the game?') it should print 'how was game'. No question mark or other stopwords. (btw, the stopwords is in the code I just cant figure out how to put it in the code box here lol  :

```
my_stopwords =  ['is', 'it', 'the', 'if', '.', 'Is', 'It', 'The', 'If']

def prep_text(sentence):
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    words_filtered= [word for word in words if not word in my_stopwords]
    return (" ").join(words_filtered)
```

Comment: There are so many NLP tutorials online, if you google how to prep data for NLP you will surely see entire articles on how to do this.

Comment: He wanted us to do it in the manual method, and it still dosen't really explain how i'd remove things such as question marks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

Comment: I wish it did. But it dosen't really clarify much about how I would need to fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

To help you out: just separate the tasks. Remove puntuation from the string prior to splitting.

```
my_punctuation_marks = '''!"#$%&'()*+, -./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'''
my_stopwords =  ['is', 'it', 'the', 'if']

def prep_text(sentence):
    for ele in sentence:
        if ele in my_punctuation_marks:
            sentence = sentence.replace(ele, " ")
    words = sentence.split(" ")
    words_filtered= [word for word in words if not word.lower() in my_stopwords if word]
    return (" ").join(words_filtered)
```